# ColdFusion and AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-ses, coldfusion-11

I am trying to setup my CF server with Amazon's SES but I guess I am doing something wrong...

This is what I did so far

• Created credentials from my AWS console
• Added the necessary settings (server, port, user/pass) in my CF admin
• Created a test script 
• No errors of any sort appeared
• No emails received and based on my AWS SES console nothing was sent out.

Anyone ever used this service before with CF and can point me to the right direction I will appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any details on your test script? What does it try to do? `<cfmail>` ?

Comment: I fixed the issue. There was another panel where you had to verify email addresses for outbound emails and also the domains that you were sending from. It's fine now :)

Comment: You should post an answer with screenshot so that if some one else get stuck on this, they will know what to do

Comment: Can you detail your CF admin mail settings here?

Comment: @DaveAnderson why would I do that?

Comment: To be helpful?  When I wrote that, I was having trouble with my own settings, but it's all sorted out.

Comment: My stumbling block, in case it's helpful to others who come upon this post, was related to the username and password.  It's not a key/secret combo that goes in there, but a username and password.  Create a new user for SES through the IAM, give that user SES rights, and use the actual username and password for the CFAdmin mail settings.  I used port 587 and enabled TLS with success.

Answer (score 2):

The below code does **not** use the CFMail tag. It allows for sending raw formatted emails, calendar invites, etc... using a CFHTTP POST to AWS SES without the constraints of the CFMAIL tag. If you want to use the CFMail TAG, see the AWS instructions for configuring an SMTP server.

Grab the following before implementing the below code:

1. [Refer to <cfLove/> Sending emails with Amazon SES API SendRawEmail in ColdFusion to construct raw email message](http://cflove.org/2013/02/using-amazon-ses-api-sendrawemail-with-coldfusion.cfm)
2. [Reference to Leigh Sv4Util.cfc for AWS v4 Signing](https://gist.github.com/Leigh-/a2798584b79fd9072605a4cc7ff60df4)

```
 NOTE: in the V4 Signing cfc -- CF16 returns the AMZDate as +0000
 for zulu. Find AMZDate (2 places) change to LEFT(AMZDate, 15) & "Z" to force
 the to end in Z -- 20200930T222905+0000 -> 0200930T222905Z.
```

3. [Refer to AWS for Sample SES Post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-ses-api-requests.html)

The sample code below assumes that attributes.mail was formatted from the sample code from CFLove and you are using the Sv4Util.cfc for signing.

```cfml
<!--- This is sample code for send to AWS SES as Raw Data Send post --->



<!--- Init Signing CFC --->
<cfset LocalVar.s4 = CreateObject('component', 'Sv4Util.cfc').init(
  accessKeyId = attributes.AWSKey
, secretAccessKey = attributes.AWSSecretKey
, defaultRegionName = attributes.AWSRegion
, defaultServiceName = "ses"
)>


<!--- 
  Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-ses-api-requests.html 
  AWS Post Example Requirements
   - Action
   - Destinations.members.?
   - Source
   - RawMessage.Data
--->

<cfset PL           = {}>
<cfset PL['Action'] = "SendRawEmail">
   

<!--- List of Email Addresses --->
<cfset count = 1>
<cfloop list="#attributes.deliverto#" index="i">
       <cfset PL["Destinations.members.#count#"] = i>
       <cfset count = count + 1>
</cfloop>

<!--- From --->
<cfset PL["Source"]          = trim(attributes.from)>

<!--- The RAW MESSAGE -- Must be encoded due to BASE64 ending with an = --->
<cfset PL["RawMessage.Data"] = URLEncodedFormat(ToBase64(trim(ArrayToList(attributes.mail,chr(10)))))>


<!--- Build URL format string for posting the above struct (PLS) --->
<cfset PLS = ''>
<cfloop list="#ListSort(structKeyList(PL), 'text', 'asc')#" index="i" >
       <cfset PLS = ListAppend(PLS,  i & "=" & PL[i], "&")>
</cfloop>

<!--- Sign Request --->
<cfset LocalVar.Signing = LocalVar.s4.generateSignatureData(  
                          requestMethod = 'POST' <!--- UPPER CASE --->
                        , hostName = 'email.#attributes.AWSRegion#.amazonaws.com'
                        , requestURI = ''
                        , requestBody = PLS
                        , requestHeaders = {"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
                        , requestParams = {}
                        )>


<!--- Do POST to AWS --->
<!--- Required in POST 
      - x-amz-content-sha256
      - Authorization
      - x-amz-date
      - content-type
      - body
--->      
<cfhttp url="https://email.#attributes.AWSRegion#.amazonaws.com" method="post" result="result">  
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-amz-content-sha256"    value="#LocalVar.Signing.RequestPayLoad#" />
       <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization"        value="#LocalVar.Signing.authorizationHeader#" />
       <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-amz-date" value="#LocalVar.Signing.AMZDate#" />
       <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
       <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#PLS#" />        
</cfhttp>
```